# Unset session when store is changed

Tags: session, store-view, switcher

Actually magento share session with differents Store/view.
Is there a way to unset session when i switch store (not website, store).
I don't want to share cart between two differents stores.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes try this in admin, `System -> Configuration -> Web -> Session Validation Settings`,

set `Use SID on Frontend` to `No`.

Remember this will log out your customer as well.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but actually this setting work only if you have different website, if you have different store/view, it don't log out and empty cart. 
We try to modify _checkGetStore function in Mage/Core/Model/App.php.
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->truncate();
Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie')->delete('frontend');
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->clear();

It work, we try now just to empty cart, it empty but when you load another page the cart come again (Cookie time...)